# Have everyone ever cannot remove doclink when using NotesRichTextDoclink.Remove

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I cannot delete doclink when using NotesRichTextDoclink.Remove

This is my Code.

[image]

1. get notesrichtextitem from rich-text field name "All"
2. set notesrichtextnavigator to the doclink
3. set notesrichtextitemlink to last element and call remove

but......

In field "All" there are not removed!

Before: There are 5 doclink

[image]

After : There are also 5 doclink!

[image]

Please help me.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you forgot to save the document after removing link as your code looks fine.

Add this line at the end of your code:

```
Call doc.Save(False, False)
```